# Como diferenciar em qual viewpager esta quando tento tirar um print com botao flutuante?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho uma view com vários fragments, adicionei um botão flutuante para tirar print da tela, mas gostaria de saber como diferenciar cada fragment para colocar nomes diferentes nas fotos.

Eu tenho o código abaixo, que tira a foto mas sobrepõe as próximas pois está com o mesmo nome.

```
@OnClick(R.id.fab_client_screenshot)
public void printScreen() {
    String fileName = "foto.png";
    JUtil.saveScreenShot(mViewPager.getRootView(), fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//retorna indice da pagina que está sendo exibida
int indicePaginaAtual = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

Comment: Vlw cara, funcionou